# Mysql group by and having with max value not return actual max value

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

```
SELECT c.testid, t.testid, c.studyid, c.PRINCIPAL, t.buildnumber 
FROM comp_max c
INNER JOIN testlog t
ON t.testid = c.testid
WHERE t.buildnumber = 1030716
ORDER BY studyid ASC
```

and the result

```
testid  testid  studyid PRINCIPAL   buildnumber
403      403    1109    2670506       1030716
497      497    1109    2468736       1030716
**495        495    1109    2468736       1030716**
442      442    1109    2468736       1030716
```

so I tried below query to get max testid (495)

```
SELECT c.testid, t.testid, c.studyid, c.PRINCIPAL, t.buildnumber 
FROM comp_max c
INNER JOIN testlog t
ON t.testid = c.testid
WHERE t.buildnumber = 1030716
group by studyid having max(c.testid)
```

But the returned value is 403 testid, not 495

```
testid  testid  studyid PRINCIPAL   buildnumber
403      403    1109    2670506       1030716
```

so the expected result would be testid 495. Could you anyone help me to figure this problem out for me? or any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed problem myself using sub-query 
here is the answer

```
SELECT c.studyid, c.testid, c.PRINCIPAL FROM comp_max c 
WHERE c.testid in (
   SELECT MAX(c.testid) FROM comp_max c
   INNER JOIN testlog t ON t.testid = c.testid
   WHERE c.studyid IN ( 
                    SELECT c.studyid FROM comp_max c 
                    INNER JOIN testlog t
                    ON t.testid = c.testid
                    WHERE t.buildnumber = 1030716 )
   AND t.buildnumber = 1030716
   GROUP  BY c.studyid )
GROUP BY studyid
ORDER BY c.studyid desc
```

I am more than happy to get your answer if you have better solution
Thanks